# Restar minutos con .reduce

Tags: kotlin, group-by

Estoy intentando restar 510 minutos por día en una tabla y convertirlo en horas.
Agrupo por días y calculo la suma de los minutos por día y lleno la lista *pagos

```
val groupHours = hoursList
                .groupingBy(HoursGroupping::fecha)
                .fold(0) { sum, res -> sum + (res.tiempoAcumulado) }

            val arrayTiempo = groupHours.values

            totalHoras = arrayTiempo.sum() - (510*arrayTiempo.count().toFloat())

            println("totalHoras - " + totalHoras/60) // 11 es lo correcto

            tiempoHorasAcumulados = totalHoras/60 // 30.5 Porque me muestra esto en la tabla?
            importeAcumulados = (tiempoHorasAcumulados!! * 10f).toInt()
            pagosAcumulados = res.pagado.toInt()
            saldo = importeAcumulados!!
            pagado = res.pagado.toInt()

            pagos.addAll(listOf(PagosText(
                        fechaGroupAcumulados!!,tiempoHorasAcumulados!!,importeAcumulados!!, pagosAcumulados!!,saldo!!))
            )
            for (res in pagos){
                println("totalHoras1 - " + res.tiempoAcumulado) // 11 en la lista se muestra correcto
            }
```

Ahora agrupo por meses desde la lista pagos obteniendo la suma del tiempo diario menos 510 minutos

```
val result = pagos
        .groupingBy { Triple(it.fecha, it.fecha, it.fecha) }
        .reduce { _, acc, element ->
            acc.copy(fecha = acc.fecha, tiempoAcumulado = acc.tiempoAcumulado + element.tiempoAcumulado, importe = acc.importe + element.importe,
                pagado = acc.pagado + element.pagado, saldo = acc.saldo + element.saldo)

        }
        .values.toList()

    for (res in result){
        println("totalHoras2 - " + res.tiempoAcumulado) // 30.5 Porque me muestra esto en el print?
    }

    var saldoAnterior = result[0].saldo; //rescatamos el primer saldo
    val result2=result.mapIndexed { index, pago ->
        if(index==0) //el primer pago lo saltamos, retornando el pago actual directamente
        {
            pago
        }
        else{ // para el pago 2 (indice=1) en adelante

            //calculamos el saldo del mes
            var saldoMes= saldoAnterior + pago.importe - pago.pagado
            saldoAnterior = saldoMes //lo guardamos como saldo anterior para la próxima iteración
            pago.copy(saldo = saldoMes) //retornamos el pago actualizado
        }
    }
```

Si en la variable *groupHours *println("totalHoras - " + totalHoras/60) me sale correcto,
¿Por qué en *tiempoHorasAcumulados = totalHoras/60 me devuelve otro valor?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno después de muchos días de matemáticas, mi error estaba en que no agrupaba los items por fecha, lo cual en todos los items me descontaba los 510 minutos.
También e agregado que no los descuente cuando es sábado o domingo

La variable result y result2, no cambian el segundo fragmento de código de la pregunta

Aquí el código.

```
                itemsDay.groupBy { it.fecha }.forEach { (fecha, items) ->
                val totalItems = items.map { it.tiempoAcumulado }.count()

                if (totalItems > 1) {
                    tiempoHorasAcumulados = (minutos.toFloat()) / 60f
                } else if (dayInSpanish == "sábado") {
                    tiempoHorasAcumulados = (minutos.toFloat()) / 60f
                } else if (dayInSpanish == "domingo") {
                    tiempoHorasAcumulados = (minutos.toFloat()) / 60f
                } else {
                    tiempoHorasAcumulados = (minutos - 510.toFloat()) / 60f
                }
            }

            importeAcumulados = (tiempoHorasAcumulados!! * 10f).toInt()
            pagosAcumulados = res.pagado.toInt()
            saldo = importeAcumulados!!
            pagado = res.pagado.toInt()

            pagos.addAll(
                listOf(PagosText( fechaGroupAcumulados!!, tiempoHorasAcumulados!!,
                    importeAcumulados!!,pagosAcumulados!!, saldo!! )
                )
            )

            val totalSaldo = pagos.sumOf { it.saldo - it.pagado }
            tvTitle.text = "Tabla de horas y cobros:\nFaltan a cobrar: ${totalSaldo}"
        }
```